# Hide and show sprites andengine Android

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a little problem/question...
I want to hide one sprite and show another one but eclipse gives me error "The local ... may not have been inatialized". Unfortunatelly I don't have another idea to hide and show those sprites... 
Can anybody help me?
Code:

```
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

    final Katapulta S_katapulta_wystrzelona = new Katapulta(10, 300, this.mKatapulta_wystrzelona, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    final Katapulta S_katapulta_zaladowana = new Katapulta(10, 300, this.mKatapulta_zaladowana, getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

    // IN THIS LINE I HAVE ERROR    S_katapulta_zaladowana.setVisible(false);


            S_katapulta_wystrzelona.setVisible(true);

            return true;
        }
    };

    scene.attachChild(S_katapulta_zaladowana);

    scene.attachChild(S_katapulta_wystrzelona);
    S_katapulta_wystrzelona.setVisible(false);

    scene.registerTouchArea(S_katapulta_zaladowana);

    return scene;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat error? Does it happen when you touch the sprite? (I assume `S_katapulta_wystrzelona` is a sprite)

Comment: Eclipse don't want to compile it. When I uncomment this line eclipse underline my S_katapulta_wystrzelona and give me error.

Comment: The local S_katapulta_zaladowana may not have been inatialized

Comment: Ok becuase you access the sprite directly with the `onAreaTouched` callback method, just use `setVisible(false);` instead of `S_katapulta_zaladowana.setVisible(false);`. tell me if that works

Comment: Kabuto178, thank you very much :) You are helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem, I faced this problem myself sometime. I will place it in an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `setVisible(false);` instead of `S_katapulta_zaladowana.setVisible(false);` Because of the way you used the `onAreaTouched()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this.

```
setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting tag to all sprites .Then call the sprite using tag and then make it Invisible

Comment: can you give me some example how do this?

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize the variable so that it is actually pointing to something it can use

ie;

```
int x = new int;
x = 69;
```

Comment: hmm how can i adapt it?

Comment: well it depends on what kind of structure datum you would want to implement for the specific purpose. for example a binary tree would work well here